# How to track product attribute changes like amazon's choice,title,stock change,new comments using ASIN with Amazon APIs?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm developing an application where I need to monitor specific product attributes from Amazon, such as whether a product has been awarded the 'Best Seller Badge' or 'Amazon's Choice', and if it's 'Fulfilled by Amazon','Title','BuyBox'. I need to do this using a product's ASIN. Additionally, I want to send notifications to users whenever any of these attributes change.

Here's what I've considered so far:

Amazon Product Advertising API doesn't seem to provide this information directly.
Amazon Selling Partner API (SP-API) offers various reports and notifications, but it's unclear if it can track these specific attributes.
I'm aware of the AWS Quick Start for Amazon SP-API reports and notifications, but need guidance on whether it can be used for these requirements.
My questions are:

Is there an Amazon API that provides access to 'Amazon's Choice' and other such attributes?
If so, how can I detect changes in these attributes for a given ASIN?
What is the best practice for implementing a notification system for these changes using Amazon's APIs?
Any guidance, especially with code examples or references to the appropriate API documentation, would be greatly appreciated.

I didn't try anything as of now but i gone through these docs but i didnt find anything except this one:=
https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/notifications-api-v1-use-case-guide#tutorial-set-up-notifications-amazon-eventbridge-workflow